# Dropbox on Linux Mint permissions issue

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, linux-mint, dropbox

I have been developing a python package in dropbox. DB seems to be causing a very strange permissions issue. I own and have RW permissions to the directory and all of it's contents. Yet, when I try to view the files, I get denied. This conflicts with my understanding of how permissions work in Unix. Can anyone explain what's going on here or how to fix it?

```
blake@mycomputer $ ls -lha .
drwxr-xr-x  6 blake blake 4.0K Apr 16 14:22 .
drwx------ 36 blake blake 4.0K Apr 16 13:11 ..
drw-rw-rw-  8 blake blake 4.0K Apr 13 02:52 myproject


blake@mycomputer $ ls myproject
ls: cannot access myproject/cache: Permission denied
ls: cannot access myproject/input: Permission denied
ls: cannot access myproject/src: Permission denied
ls: cannot access myproject/archive: Permission denied
ls: cannot access myproject/output: Permission denied
ls: cannot access myproject/log: Permission denied
archive  cache  input  log  output  src
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory does not have the search (x) permission, which is where the permission denied error do:

```
chmod ugo+x myproject
```

To add it for user, group and other.